# Alternate to body onload = (string) for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onload

I'm (somewhat) new to JavaScript and I'm writing a timing plugin that requires

```
<body onload="mktClock_standard(); setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 ); mktClock_military(); setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 )">
```

And I was wondering if there's a way to do that, but in JavaScript, like using `window.onload` or something. I tried simply:

```
window.onload = mktClock_standard(); setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 ); mktClock_military(); setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 )
```

But **obviously** there are so many wrong syntax errors and stuff, so... I went to Google but I could not find anything relating to my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`window.onload` is the exact same thing as the `onload` attribute, but it expects a function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    mktClock_standard(); 
    setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 ); 
    mktClock_military(); 
    setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 )
}
```

Actually, when you add code to attributes like `<body onload="code...">`, the browser will treat them as if there were a wrapping anonymous function.

Also, modern browsers support the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which is similar, but fires ealier. It fires as soon as the DOM is loaded, while `window.onload` waits for other resources (such as images) to be loaded. To bind to `DOMContentLoaded`, use `addEventListener`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(evt) {
    // event handler code here
});
```

(The above won't work in IE8 and earlier)

Comment: Tip: instead of passing `'mktClock_standard()'` to `setInterval`, pass `mktClock_standard` (as a reference, not a string, and without the parentheses). That way, you [avoid evil `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a function declaration:

```
window.onload = function() {
    mktClock_standard();
    setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 ); 
    mktClock_military(); 
    setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to attach your event. All need to have a function enclosing your statements.

Using the [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload) event handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
  mktClock_standard(); 
  setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 ); 
  mktClock_military(); 
  setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 );
};
```

Or using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

```
window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  mktClock_standard(); 
  setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 ); 
  mktClock_military(); 
  setInterval('mktClock_standard()', 1000 );
} );
```